# how to use combobox as a dropdown list and textbox in asp.net like combobox

Tags: asp.net

how to use combobox as a dropdown list and textbox  in asp.net like combobox in windows forms?
please help 
when we use ajax toolkit combobox it allows only dropdown list

2)i am getting error in file upload(using ajax toolkit)?

Answer (score 1):

HTML4 does not include any `<input>` element that provides functionality similar to Windows' ComboBox control - you have to use separate `<input type="text">` and `<select>` elements as fallback.

HTML5 does provide for this via the `<datalist>` element, which is currently supported by all current-version browsers except Safari (for both Mac OS X and iOS): http://caniuse.com/datalist

For everything else, I strongly suggest using jQuery's Autocomplete add-in which has a combobox mode: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox